# Describe all orthogonal matrices in $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

> If $G = \{ A \in GL(3,\mathbb R): Ax = x \}$, where $x = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 0\\
> 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$, describe all orthogonal matrices in $G$.

Comment: Not quite. Given your matrix, if you multiply it by your vector $x$, you don't get $x$ back as an output. Try to restructure the matrix so that this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix represents an isometry of Euclidean space - it preserves the magnitude of any vector and the dot product of any two vectors. $G$ consists of the orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrices which also leave the $x$ axis unchanged.

Your example is a family of orthogonal matrices, but they do not leave the $x$ axis unchanged. Instead, they map the $z$ acis to the $y$ axis.

Comment: I see. If I wanted x-axis unchanged, the matrix would be $\pmatrix{1 & b & c \\ 0 & e & f \\ 0 & f & -e}$ ?

Comment: @FoolieWithDaToolie yes, and then the requirement that the matrix is orthogonal puts further constraints on the values of $b,c,e,f$.